# 2001 Saturn L-200 replacing one tire

Tags: rough-idle

So, today I was driving and all of the sudden my front passenger tire blew out. I pull over to find out that I ran over some piece of metal and the tire is torn unrepairable. Luckily there was a tires plus right around the corner and I got the tire replaced. Now, after they replaced the tire, and I don't know if this is from the blow out or not, but when the car is under 700 (yes seven-hundred not thousand) RPM's it shakes, but if you turn on the air conditioner it hits a sweet spot and idles perfectly fine. Obviously this is negligible when actually driving due to the RPMs being higher. I don't know if this matters either, but it is fine when in park or neutral, but the car idles at about 1k RPM's in those gears. The car is an automatic by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Not surprised it shakes, being under 700 rpms sounds a bit on the low side for an engine that small. I'd expect it to be around 750 rpms normally.  You may have a faulty Idle Air Controller (or something similar, not familiar with Saturns).

Answer (score 1):

Took it to the shop, broke an engine mount bracket which is causing the shake. Also, the tubes are torn on the AC. – Cody Bennett just now edit